# SelectList within a foreach loop

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the following code in a controller:

```
    public static IEnumerable<SelectListItem> EventStatus = new[] {
        new SelectListItem{ Text=Active, Value=Active},
        new SelectListItem{ Text=CheckedIn, Value=CheckedIn},
        new SelectListItem{ Text=Inactive, Value=Inactive}
    };

    ViewData["EventStatus"] = EventStatus;
```

I'm trying to iterate through a foreach loop in an .aspx file and binding the value to the SelectList.

```
<% foreach (var item in Model) { %>
....
<%= Html.DropDownList("item.Status", ViewData["EventStatus"] as SelectList)%>
...
```

This isn't working. I'm getting:

> There is no ViewData item with the key
>   'item.Status' of type
>   'IEnumerable'.

but `<%= Html.Encode(item.Status) %>` works.

I also tried this:

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("item.Status", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewData["EventStatus"])%>
```

This displays the list, but nothing is selected (no binding occurs).

Anyone have any suggestions?

Cheers,

Dean

Answer (score 1):

You do not have to loop through to bind item to a control like DropDownList or ListBox just do this

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("ControlName",  ViewData["EventStatus"] as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)%>
```

for DropDownList and like this

```
 <%= Html.ListBox("ControlName", ViewData["EventStatus"] as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)%>
```

for ListBox

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use view models instead of ViewData. This way your views will be strongly typed. For example you could have the following view model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Status { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> EventStatuses
    {
        get
        {
            return new SelectList(new[] 
            {
                new SelectListItem{ Text = Active, Value = Active },
                new SelectListItem{ Text = CheckedIn, Value = CheckedIn },
                new SelectListItem{ Text = Inactive, Value = Inactive }
            }, "Value", "Text");
        }
    }
}
```

and then in your controller:

```
public class HomeController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new MyViewModel());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(MyViewModel model)
    {
        // TODO: Do something with the selected model.Status
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

and finally the strongly typed view:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm()) { %>
    <%= Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Status, Model.EventStatuses) %>
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you post a bit more of your controller. What you have shown wouldn't build, is it actual source or did u type it in?

It looks like when the view is executing ViewData["EventStatus"] is null. If you put:

```
<%= ViewData["EventStatus"] == null %>
```

in your view does it come up true or false?

From Mvc2 Source (SelectExtensions.SelectInternal):

```
if (selectList == null) {
            selectList = htmlHelper.GetSelectData(name);
            usedViewData = true;
        }
```

selectList is the list that was passed in. As you can see if it is null it attempts to get a value from the view data using the "name" (which in this case is "item.Status").